# Showing that $\frac{1}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n} = O(e^{\pi\sqrt{n/6}})$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

Here's a small introduction on what I am doing skip to the %%%%%%%%%% if you just want the question.

Definition:  We say that $f(z) << g(z)$ if $|f(z)| \leq |g(z)| \quad \forall z \in D$.

In the book I'm reading (Analytic Number Theory, Donald J. Newman, page 25), they proved the fact that

$$p(n) - q(n) << M\frac{((1-r)^{5/2}}{r^n}\exp\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{1}{1-r}\right).$$

With a clever choice of $r = 1- \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}}$ they want to show that

$$p(n) = q(n) + O\left(n^{-5/4} e^{\pi\sqrt{2n/3}}\right).$$

It is clear for me that the $n^{-5/4}$ comes from the $(1-r)^{5/2}.$
It is also clear for me that $e^{\pi\sqrt{n/6}}$ comes from the $\exp\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{1}{1-r}\right)$.

If I could show that
$$\frac{1}{r^n} = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n}$$
brings another
$$e^{\pi\sqrt{n/6}}$$
in the $O$, I would be done with my understanding on this chapter.

I first thought that I could say
$$\frac{1}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n} = \frac{1}{((1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^\sqrt{n})^\sqrt{n}}
=(e^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}})^{\sqrt{n}}=e^{\pi\sqrt{n/6}}.$$

But I did calculate the limit in one part of the equation and letting a $n$ untouched.

I could also try to show that 
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{-\pi\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{6}}}}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n} = k \quad \quad k \in \mathcal{R}$$

Then I would have a clean argument for my question which is:

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Is there anyone who could write me a valid argument for the fact that
$$\frac{1}{r^n} = \frac{1}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n} = O(e^{\pi\sqrt{n/6}}).$$

(This is my first time manipulating big $O$ notation.)

Comment: Are you sure the authors define $\ll$ as "being uniformly less than"? This is odd.

Comment: At first I thought it meant that there exists a real constant $c$ such that
$$|f(z)| \leq c|g(z)|. $$

But with investigation, it seems that the constant is always 1. 
Does that clarify your question?

Comment: Where do they define $\ll$ in the book?

Comment: In fact they don't. The author doesn't define most of the definition in this book. I personally made the definition from my understanding of the chapter.

Comment: Then let us hope (for you) that $f(n)\ll g(n)$ indeed has the meaning of $|f(n)|\leqslant |g(n)|$ and not the (more canonical) meaning of $f(n)/g(n)\to0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by writing
$$\tag{1}
\frac{1}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n}=\exp\left[-n\log\left(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}}\right)\right]
$$
Now, recall the power series for $\log(1-x)$:
$$
\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n},\qquad\lvert x\rvert<1.
$$
In particular, $\log(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$, so that
$$
\log\left(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$
Plugging this in to (1), we find
$$
\frac{1}{(1-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6n}})^n}=\exp\left[\pi\sqrt{\frac{n}{6}}+O(1)\right]=O(e^{\pi\sqrt{n/6}}),
$$
as desired. (This last step holds because $e^{O(1)}$ is, itself, $O(1)$ -- that is, bounded above by a constant.)